# Using global filters to apply role authorization to entire mvc app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, global-asax

I'm using a global authorization filter on my MVC app to ensure that users are authenticated before they access my app, but I'd like to take it one step further.  I have three AD groups that the users can potenially be a member of and I'd like the global filter to check for one of those three groups as well.

I do not want to add three authorize attributes to every controller in my application.  How would I write the global filter to include role authorization?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a Role-Based membership provider , which essentially will call an Authorize service with your custom logic and you can mention the roles in a config file you need to check against. This entire logic can be encapsulated inside an attribute , decorated over the Routes.